# Ratios to determine company's current purchasing power

Tags: applied-econometrics, corporate-finance, purchasing-power-partity

what are the parameters which will affect a company ability to buy a new product based on its current financial situation.  Is there any metrics or ratios which will tell the current company purchasing power?

Comment: This question seems to be more of an accounting question than an economic question.

Comment: newbie to economics..actually a CS major...I thought economics is superset  of finance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably get a very good idea of a company's ability to spend money - that is, make capital investments, develop new ventures etc. - by investing its balance sheet and develop both liquidity and leverage ratios. High liquidity with low leverage means that a company is probably not investing enough. Low liquidity with high leverage ratios would indicate a company has already invested heavily and is not in a position to undertake new ventures etc.

- [Here is a good introduction to leverage ratios](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/investing/080113/understanding-leverage-ratios.asp)
- [Here is a good introduction to liquidity ratios](http://www.investopedia.com/university/ratios/liquidity-measurement/)